window move up when new data in pagination
I have a problem with my code with pagination, i have a requests list and when i am at the end of the list i use fetchMore to add new data, and continue to scroll data, but when there is a fetch window is moving up, the window don't stay at his position...?
function MyRequest() {
    //state
    const [requests, setRequests] = useState<RequestProps[]>([]);
    const [offset, setOffset] = useState(0);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const scrollPosition = useRef(0);
    const limit = 4;

    // store
    const id = userDataStore((state) => state.id);

    //mutation
    const [ deleteRequest, {error: deleteRequestError} ] = useMutation(DELETE_REQUEST_MUTATION);

    // Query to get the user requests
    const {getUserRequestsData, fetchMore} = useQueryUserRequests(id, offset, limit);
    console.log('getUserRequestsData', getUserRequestsData);

    useEffect(() => {
        // Restore scroll position
        window.scrollTo(0, scrollPosition.current);
    }, [requests]);

    // useEffect to update the requests state
    useEffect(() => {
        if (getUserRequestsData) {
            // Save scroll position
            scrollPosition.current = window.scrollY;
            // If offset is 0, it's the first query, so just replace the queries
            if (offset === 0) {
                setRequests(getUserRequestsData.user.requests);
            } else {
            
                setRequests(prevRequests => [...prevRequests, ...getUserRequestsData.user.requests]);
            }
            
        }

    }, [getUserRequestsData]);

    // Function to delete a request
    const handleDeleteRequest = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>, requestId: number, imageNames: string[]) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        deleteRequest({
            variables: 
                { input: 
                    {
                        id: requestId,
                        user_id: id,
                        image_names: imageNames
                    }
                }
        }).then((response) => {
            if (response.data.deleteRequest) {
                // Remove the request from the state
                setRequests(requests.filter(request => request.id !== requestId));
            }
        });

        if (deleteRequestError) {
            throw new Error('Error while deleting request');
        }
        
    };
    
    // Function to handle scroll event
    const handleScroll = () => {
        if (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY >= document.documentElement.scrollHeight - 100) {
        // Reached the bottom of the page
            if (!loading) {
                setLoading(true);
                fetchMore({
                    variables: {
                        offset: requests.length // Next offset
                    },
                    updateQuery: (prev, { fetchMoreResult }) => {
                        if (!fetchMoreResult) return prev;
                        setOffset(prevOffset => prevOffset + fetchMoreResult.user.requests.length); // Update offset
                        setLoading(false);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    };
    // useEffect to add event listener to handle scroll event
    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
        };
    }, [loading]);

i tried to use event.preventDefault() but it doesn't work, and i tried to save scroll position but doesn't work too.
